# Exclude PMD rule in build.gradle file

Tags: java, gradle, pmd

I'm using Gradle to configure and run PMD over my source code. My build gradle file contains the following configuration for the PMD plugin:

```
pmd {
    ruleSets = [
        'java-android',
        'java-basic',
        'java-braces',
        ...,
        'java-controverial'
    ]
}
```

I've have explicity enabled all checks within my build.gradle file and wish to disable those I deem unnecessary as I encounter them. The first rule I wish to disable is the [`UnnecessaryConstructor`](https://pmd.github.io/pmd-5.5.1/pmd-java/rules/java/controversial.html#UnnecessaryConstructor) rule.

Can I disable this rule from within my build.gradle file, or must I define an xml rules file and disable the rule from within there?

Comment: Just comment them out with //

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to define the XML in a file, you can define it inline via the incubating [ruleSetConfig](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.plugins.quality.PmdExtension.html#org.gradle.api.plugins.quality.PmdExtension:ruleSetConfig) property.

Here an example in Kotlin DSL:

```
pmd {
    ruleSetConfig = resources.text.fromString(
        """
            <the rule set config here>
        """.trimIndent()
    )
}
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, but given the choice I would rather build an xml rules file, rather than mixing grooxy and xml (which would have me rightfully flamed on review!). If that is the only option then I better start rolling that rules file :).

Comment: You can use a `MarkupBuilder` to generate the XML with Groovy code.

Answer (score -1):

use below snippet in your build.gradle

```
pmd {
    sourceSets = [ project.sourceSets.main ]
    ruleSetFiles = rootProject.files("codequality/pmd-ruleset.xml")
    ruleSets = []

    pmdMain {
        excludes = [
                '**/Application.*'
        ]
    }
}
```